# How to compare 2 different String literals byte by byte in RUST

Tags: arrays, rust, slice, string-comparison

I entered two string literals and converted them into arrays of bytes and now I'm trying to compare both arrays bytes to check for a match. If they match successfully, I want to save it into an unknown size array `find`, but it is not saving:

```
fn main() {
    let mut m: u8 = 0;
    // enter the first_name
    let alpha = "fawad";
    //covert name1 into array bytes
    let name1 = alpha.as_bytes();
    // enter the second_name
    let input = String::new();
    //covert name2 into array bytes
    let name2 = input.as_bytes();
    //want to create an unknown size of an array
    let find: Box<[u8]>;
    for (i, &place1) in name1.iter().enumerate() {
        let place1 = name1[i];
        for (j, &place2) in name2.iter().enumerate() {
            let place2 = name2[j];
            if place1 == place2 {
                let find = place2;
                m = m + 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    println!("comparison shows {:?}", find);
}
```

I get:

```
error: expected one of `:`, `;`, `=`, or `@`, found `[`
  --> src\main.rs:17:13

   |
17 |     let find[] : Box<[u8]>;
   |             ^ expected one of `:`, `;`, `=`, or `@` here
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. The code you have provided does not produce the error you are asking about. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Your error message also appears to refer to code that isn't present.

Comment: It **really** seems like you want `alpha == input`, but you haven't defined what the value of `find` should be when they *aren't* equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler message is not reproducable, yet your code reveals some misunderstandings. Here some hints how you could change it:

You want an array of unknown size (and it shall probably contain the bytes already matched, so it must be mutable):

- replace `let find : Box<[u8]>;` by `let mut find = Vec::new();`

You want to iterate the bytes of name1 and name2

- replace `for (i, &place1) in name1.iter().enumerate()` by `for &place1 in name1.iter()`
- replace `for (i, &place2) in name2.iter().enumerate()` by `for &place2 in name2.iter()`

`let variable = ...` shadows all former definitions of `variable`. You do not want to shadow the variables `place1`, `place2` you want to use these variables.

- remove `let place1 = name1[i];`
- remove `let place2 = name2[j];`

You want to add the matching byte to the array `find`. Your code will again shadow the definition of find. So

- replace `let find = place2;` by `find.push(place2);`